# Model Difference In View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view In ASP MVC With Model StockVM .. but Seems that it bind with Stock Model..I have Re Built Many time But It Refer To Stock Model

[Image Of VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUu3a.png)

Comment: Show your StockVM. Also, if you right click the property and choose "Go to definition", where does it take you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's visual studio IDE problems.

You can restart Visual studio to fix problems.

If intellisense not work correctly after restart , delete all file under this folder : `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`